# Inheritance of Square method in java

Tags: java, inheritance, rectangles

I have a class Rectangle laid out like this:

```
package Inheritance;

/**
 *
 * @author Jacob
 */
public class Rectangle {
final private int length;
final private int width;

public Rectangle (int l, int w)
{
    length = l;
    width = w;
}

public int getLength ()
{
    return length;
}

public int getWidth ()
{
    return width;
}

@Override
public String toString ()
{
    return String.format ("Rectangle (%dX%d)", length, width);
}

}
```

I then need to create class square in the following way:

ad Square: 
Square extends Rectangle /
No fields are declared in class Square / 
It has a parameterized constructor with (only) one parameter /
The parameter is used to initialize both fields of Rectangle /
It has a method called getSide to expose the side-length of the square /
Override the toString method so that it will return a String of the following form: / Square(side)      e.g. Square(4)

The values for the sides are going to be hard coded. Rectangle is going to have a width of 4. In order to get the side of the square to be 4 do I create an instance of rectangle and call the method getWidth and set that as the side length. Thats how I would think to do it but in that case I would only be using one of the fields so, My question is how do I initialize both fields? Can I call Rectangle and make length and width equal or is there some other way I should do it?

Here is the code for my Square class:

```
public class Square {

    public Square (int side)
    {
        super(side, side);
    }

    public int getSide ()
    {
        return side;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        return String.format ("Square (%d)", side);
    }
}
```

For the line super(side, side) I get the error constructor Object in class Object cannot be applied to given types. Required no arguments, found int, int. For my return statements I get that it cannot find the variable side.

Comment: smell like a home work. is it?

Comment: In `Square`, you should be taking a single parameter which is the size, you would then simply need to call `super(size, size)` within the `Square`s constructor...

Comment: You should probably start by following a book or a tutorial. Like the Java Tutorial's section on [inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html)

Comment: "The values for the sides are going to be hard coded." I assume that you mean these values are hardcoded in `main()` or wherever you create `Rectangle` and `Square` objects. They absolutely should **not** be hardcoded any where else.

Comment: Yes, The values will be hard coded in the main method where the objects will be created.

Answer (score 0):

> The values for the sides are going to be hard coded.

I assume that you mean that you will hardcode the values for the width and length when you create a `Rectangle` and `Square` object (for example in `main()`). These values should absolutely **not** be hardcoded any where in the `Rectangle` and `Square` classes.

> Rectangle is going to have a width of 4. In order to get the side of the square to be 4 do I create an instance of rectangle and call the method getWidth and set that as the side length.

Not at all. Rather, `Square` should have its own constructor which calls the `Rectangle` constructor with the same value for both the `width` and `length`:

```
public Square(int side) {
    super(side, side); // Set the width and length to the same value.
}
```

Comment: I attempted to use super but I put length and width as the parameters. I corrected with what you had suggested but it says that super required no arguments. Also when writing the getSide method am I returning the width from the getWidth method?

Comment: @user3440443 Please show the code for your Square class in order for us to help you.

Comment: I added the Square class.

Comment: I managed to figure  it out after some more research on my own. I didn't understand which class of my five classes was the superclass or to tell if one was. I found out that I had to define my Square class as the subclass in my class declaration. I then called super.getWidth () to get my value for my side as they will be the same. The whole time I wasn't able to figure that out because I was working on understanding the logic for my problem and then the syntax for the super command. After I had tried incorporate your suggestion for the syntax I had researched the error with no luck.